# How to write a TVF that accepts 3 parameters and returns a table that includes the IDs of the rows that match the criteria from another table

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am new to Table-Valued Functions and am having trouble getting this function off the ground. 
I am trying to create a function that accepts 3 parameters(@Lat decimal, @Long decimal, @RangeInMiles int).
What I want to do is return the location IDs from a Locations table that are within the radius of the passed parameter: @RangeInMiles.

The Location table includes the following columns: 
loc_ID PK IDENTITY
(Typical address stuff)
loc_longitude
loc_latitude

So the thought is to have this function use the lat and long that was passed to compare against the lats and longs in the Locations table and return those IDs that are within the passed radius: @RangeInMiles.

All the code I have so far is below, but I'm stumped at the WHERE clause. Thanks for the help!

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAvailableSalesByDistance(@Lat decimal, @Long decimal, @RangeInMiles int)
RETURNS @LocationIds Table
(loc_ID int)
AS
BEGIN INSERT @LocationIds
SELECT Locations.loc_ID
FROM Locations
WHERE 
RETURN
END
```

Comment: It seems you need Pythagoras. Triangle functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, following Pythagoras:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAvailableSalesByDistance(@Lat decimal, @Long decimal, @RangeInMiles int)
RETURNS @LocationIds Table
(loc_ID int)
AS
BEGIN INSERT INTO@LocationIds
SELECT Locations.loc_ID
FROM Locations as l
WHERE (SQRT(SQUARE(l.loc_latitude-@Lat)+SQUARE(l.loc_longitude-@Long))<=@RangeInMiles)
RETURN
END
```

If you want to locate false data you could try this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Locations
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(numeric, loc_latitude) IS NULL
OR TRY_CONVERT(numeric, loc_longitude) IS NULL
```

Edit:
To get it right you could use haversine:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAvailableSalesByDistance(@Lat decimal, @Long decimal, @RangeInMiles int)
    RETURNS @LocationIds Table
    (loc_ID int)
    AS
    BEGIN INSERT INTO@LocationIds
    SELECT Locations.loc_ID
    FROM Locations as l
    WHERE 
(2 * 3961 * asin(sqrt((sin(radians((l.loc_latitude - @Lat) / 2))) ^ 2 + cos(radians(@Lat)) * cos(radians(l.loc_latitude)) * (sin(radians((l.loc_longitude - @Long) / 2))) ^ 2))) <=@RangeInMiles)
    RETURN
    END
```

It’s not tested and comes from this [source](http://daynebatten.com/2015/09/latitude-longitude-distance-sql/)

Comment: Thank you @Nikolaus. I tried your approach and I am getting the following error when I call the function:

Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

This was my call:
SELECT * FROM GetAvailableSalesByDistance(34.10, 84.52,5)

Comment: @JP1 Could it be, that loc_latidude or/and loc_longidude are of type nvarchar?

Comment: You're right, they are! Which would be better for this function: Switch the data type of the Lat and Long on the Locations Table of change the Function itself?

Comment: Usually, it should work this way too, but maybe you have data, that isn’t convertible to decimal. Like letters in one of the two columns.

Comment: @JP1 You could try to find out, if you have invalid data.

Comment: @JP1 If updated my answer with a statement to locate invalid data.

Comment: I only have numbers in there. Not sure what is going on?

Comment: Actually, It's really strange, I just tried the call again and it worked! I'm going to run a few more tests!

Comment: Okay. After testing, this isn't working correctly. I am trying to do a radius search and I don't think this is working correctly because we are treating this as math and not using the Geography type?

Comment: @JP1 I‘ve updated my answer. Did you try the new version?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement with updated clause could be:

```
INSERT @LocationIds
        SELECT
            Locations.loc_ID 
        FROM
            Locations 
        WHERE
            SQRT(SQUARE(loc_longitude - @Long) + SQUARE(loc_latitude - @Lat)) <= @RangeInMiles
```

Answer (score 0):

This is far more complicated than what @Nikolaus posted, latitude and longitude are on a sphere (Earth) and are not expressed in miles, so Pythagorean triple does not apply here. Following [formula explained here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), we'll get the following function in SQL Server to calculate the distance:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.spatialDistance(@lat1 DECIMAL, @lon1 DECIMAL, @lat2 DECIMAL, @lon2 DECIMAL)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT 6371 * Calc2.c AS DistanceKm
         , 3958.8 * Calc2.c AS DistanceMi
      FROM (SELECT RADIANS(@lat1) AS Lat1
                 , RADIANS(@lat2) AS Lat2
                 , RADIANS(@lat2 - @lat1) AS dLat
                 , RADIANS(@lon2 - @lon1) AS dLon) conv
     CROSS
     APPLY (SELECT a = SQUARE(SIN(dLat/2.0)) + SQUARE(SIN(dLon/2.0)) * COS(Lat1) * COS(Lat2)) Calc1
     CROSS
     APPLY (SELECT c = 2 * ATN2(SQRT(Calc1.a), SQRT(1 - Calc1.a))) AS Calc2
)
```

You could then write your desired function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAvailableSalesByDistance(@Lat decimal, @Long decimal, @RangeInMiles int)
RETURNS Table
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT l.loc_id
      FROM Locations AS l
     CROSS
     APPLY dbo.spatialDistance(l.loc_latitude, l.loc_longitude, @Lat, @Long) dist
     WHERE dist.DistanceMi <= @RangeInMiles
)
```

Note I'm using inline table-valued functions. Scalar functions and multi statement TVFs like you used in your question are terrible for performance and should not be used. [See here for explanation if you're interested](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4689/understand-the-performance-behavior-of-sql-server-scalar-user-defined-functions/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! This makes sense. I am still getting the error that it can't convert varchar to numeric when I run the function call. Thoughts?

Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. 

This was my call: SELECT * FROM GetAvailableSalesByDistance(34.10, 84.52,5)

Comment: @JP1 How is your Locations table defined? `loc_latitude` and `loc_longitude` are `nvarchar`? If so, `TRY_CONVERT` query posted by @Nikolaus should reveal those. Maybe you forgot to drop the previous version of `GetAvailableSalesByDistance` before creating my version?

Comment: Yes, they are nvarchar. I'll have to find a way to convert those columns to numeric, it would appear. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @JP1 They should automatically convert, some just fail. Have you tried `SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL, loc_latitude) IS NULL OR TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL, loc_longitude) IS NULL`? This should list all the records that are failing to convert. Maybe using comma instead of a dot as a decimal separator?